# implementing curtain transition of imageviews in android

Tags: android, animation

I want to implement the curtain animation like in ios in my application.For this i have taken a framelayout and added two linear layout and in the top most linear layout i have put two imageviews and i am applying translate up and down to the imageviews.

It is working ,but the problem is that it is not smooth as compared to the ios.Does anybody have any better solution for smooth transition of the image views?

Answer (score 0):

The smoothness of the transition will be dependent mostly on the device and it's computing power. Have you tried your app on an actual device, or just the emulator. It might just be running slow on the emulator.

Also, perhaps its the loading of the images that are causing things to be slow. Have you tried caching them in memory?

Comment: yes i have tried that on real devices like xoom,galaxy 3.0.Sometime it is smooth and sometimes it is not.Do you have any better approach for curtain transition?